# definite article with "the most"

Tags: adverbs, definite-article

I was told that the following sentences are wrong:

> 1. I'm the one who drives the car most.
> 2. I'm the one who drives most the car

It seems acceptable TO ME using **"most"** in this way. I have the impression that it acts as an adverb over "drives".

---

And I also was told that the following is right:

> 3. I'm the one who drives the car the most.

Wouldn't just the first article be enough? I say this because according to the ["English club"](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/determiners-order.htm), we can only have one "main determiner" in a noun phrase.

Comment: Sentences 1 and 3 are correct and natural. Sentence 2 is arguably bad grammar, and at best highly unnatural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In some contexts, using it one way or the other can change the meaning. For example, "*I eat most food*" would mean that you eat most *kinds* of food, whereas "*I eat the most food*" would mean you eat more food than anyone else in the context of what you are speaking about (eg in your family, in your peer group).

Your examples 1 and 3 are both correct. The context of this specific example doesn't make any difference which you use.

1. I'm the one who drives the car most.
2. <s>I'm the one who drives most the car</s>
3. I'm the one who drives the car the most.

Example 2 is wrong. But instead of 'most', you could use the adverb 'mostly' and say:

- I'm the one who *mostly* drives the car.

Comment: Right, it is a superlative adverb. Worth saying.

Comment: Thank you, people :))